# css: right-aligned element is off-screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap for my css and the following code has an issue with the alignment:

see jsfiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/99rhF/  (make sure you enlarge the html view)

```
<div class="view-header">
 <span class="view-title">Recherche de mandats</span>
<div class="pull-right">
<a style="line-height: 30px; margin-right: 20px; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;">
    <span class="pointer">more options</span>
</a>
<form class="form-inline pull-left" placeholder="N° de contrat, nom/numéro de client" css-class="input-xxlarge">
    <input class="input-xxlarge ng-dirty" type="text" placeholder="N° de contrat, nom/numéro de client" ng-model="model">
    <button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-info" type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i>&nbsp;Rechercher</button>
</form>
</div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="pull-right">
</div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>
```

as you can see the button with the label 'Rechercher' is too far right. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can't get you? Please explain in brief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your button, its the containing element.

Update the css with:

```
 .view-header {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Removing `width: 100%;` Div's are block line elements, meaning they will fill their parent. This should solve your problem.

See: 
http://jsfiddle.net/99rhF/2/

Comment: I was not able to follow his question.  Is the problem with scroll? I find only that difference in your fiddle

Comment: np sam, interestingly. Although a bit new and fresh you could also look at: `flex-box` It stops the padding getting added to the items width so that it is included instead. Very nice stuff this flex-box is.3

Answer (score 1):

The parent element has a width of 100%, but padding isn't included in width calculations, so it ends up being 100% + 40px. You fix this by wrapping the contents in a container, and padding that instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/ndTuL/

```
.view-header {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #bbbbbb;
}

.content-wrap {
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I ended up using Jamie's answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I know I'm late to the party :)

Second - `@Jamie Hutber` has a very good and valid answer. No arguments here at all - it should remain the accepted answer for sure.

Third - Here's what I ran in to, and how I fixed it:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $str->head; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <footer>
        &copy; Copyright 2021-$currentYear | All Rights Reserved | No Unauthorized Use Permitted | JPeG Web Development
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

`<footer>` is also a Block Line Element, so `width` is not needed. Here's what I did instead:

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #f8f3ed;
    max-width: 1200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Things to note is that the `position: absolute;` will mess up any `text-direction` and make it overflow, *especially if you try and add a `width: 100%` to it*. The `right` and `bottom` stick it on the bottom right corner no matter how much you scroll.

It's not exactly what the question was asking, but I thought it might be nice for people to see some alternate ways to have this issue, and resolve it.